# How to get Resolve Project Problems dialogue in Netbeans?

Tags: gradle, netbeans

I have an issue with a minimal Spring Boot Gradle project in Netbeans – minimal as in basic project from Sring Initilizr with zero dependencies. The Priming Build doens't happen as it should. Nothing in the project tree is marked as an error except the project itself. The message associated with that project-level error says *Unresolved project problem, fix by "Resolve Project Problems".*

There is nothing in the Netbeans menu for Resolve Project Problems. The only reference I could find was to right-click the project… But there is no Resolve Project Problems there, either.

[image: Where is Resolve Project Problems]

How do I get to the Resolve Project Problems dialog to try to make sense of this?

Comment: [1] That looks like a NetBeans bug. There should be a menu entry _Resolve Project Problems..._ immediately above the _Properties_ entry at the bottom of the context menu for any project with _"project problems"_. [2] If you restart NetBeans there should be an **Open Project** dialog displayed if any projects have problems. Do you see that? [3] Also, the name of any project with "project problems" should be shown in red font in the Projects panel. Do you see that for _"test-a"_? [4] Finally, have you tried to **Clean and Build** your _test-a_ project to see if the issue goes away?

Comment: Thanks @skomisa. Restarting made no difference. No project names are ever in red. Clean and Build didn't help (oh, the number of times I tried that). I figured out that the underlying problem was version incompatibility (Java 17 requires NB 12.6), but that doesn't explain why, as you say, the Resolve menu option isn't present. Of course, would they consider it a bug or user error?

Comment: [1] It's a bug. I have projects in 12.5 that have similar JDK issues, and after right clicking on those projects the context menu shows a _"Resolve Project Problems..."_ entry one up from the bottom. [2] You can [report the problem to NetBeans here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-5702?filter=allopenissues). [3] Also, I have no idea why you are getting that specific error because NetBeans 12.5 definitely supports Java 17, and I'm using it. From [the 12.5 Release Notes](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb125/nb125.html): _"experimental support for JDK 17"_.